# stably finite $C^*$ algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

I saw a conlusion:If $A$ is simple $C^*$ algebra,then $A\otimes \Bbb K$ contains no infinite projections?

If $A$ is simple, $A\otimes \Bbb K $ contains no infinite projections,can we conclude that $A$ is stably finite?

Answer (score 1):

Take any simple, purely infinite C$^*$-algebra; for instance, $\mathcal O_2$. Then $A\otimes\mathbb K$ contains lots of infinite projetions: $1\otimes p$ is infinite for any projection $p$.

The second question is easily answered if you notice that $M_n(A)=A\otimes M_n(\mathbb C)$ embeds in $A\otimes \mathbb K$.

Comment: One should also notice that the union of the $A \otimes M_n$ is dense.

Comment: That depends on how you embed.

Comment: what troubled me is the following statement in Blackdar's book:If $A$ is simple exact and stable,A contatins an infinite projection iff there is no nondegenerate trace on A.I know there also exists a theorem:A simple exact C* algebra A has a trace iff A is stably finite.Suppose A is stably finite,then $A\otimes \Bbb K$ has no infinite projections,then  $A\otimes \Bbb K$ has a trace,how could this happen?If $A\otimes K$ has a trace,then$\Bbb K$ has a trace,but there is no trace on $\Bbb K$.

Comment: I cannot comment on where you got the "theorem" from, but $\mathbb K $ is simple, exact, stably finite, and has no trace.